# CSS background image won't load

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I've been making a website for a fake business to improve my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript skills. However I can't get my background image to load, if you could take a look at my code to see whats wrong, that would be great.

[Link to GitHub release](https://github.com/thomasschultz9326/Web-Stuff/releases/tag/v1.0)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `background-image: url("Images/pexels-photo-coffee-main.jpeg");`

Comment: See my answer on the difference between your code and how it should work ;) Also it's best to post your code here next time as not a lot of people will download a random zip file despite it being on github.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the image file which is in the parent folder, so you need to use two dots`(../)` to get to parent folder and then `../Images/image.jpeg`

Use this

CSS

```
background-image: url("../Images/pexels-photo-coffee-main.jpeg");
```

Comment: Ok thank you guys, I apparently didn't have my url link setup right, ../ was the problem, thanks again for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `../` instead of `./`

`../` will send you up a directory and `./` will leave you in the current directory.

So your line:

```
background-image: url("./Images/pexels-photo-coffee-main.jpeg");
```

should actually be:

```
background-image: url("../Images/pexels-photo-coffee-main.jpeg");
```

*Note* if you want to go back multiple directories then you can do `../../../` that would go back up 3 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure directory structure is right. Check this example

```
 html
   |-assets/css/
   |-assets/js/
   |-assets/images/
   index.html
```

then when you want to load images make sure in css your code is

```
background-image: url('assets/images/image_file.jpg');
```

Comment: This won't work as it would have to be `url("../assets/images/image_file.jpg")` you still need to go to the parent folder.

Comment: it's work when index.html inside root html folder . you need double dot ( .. ) when index.html inside folder like pages/index.html

or to make sure images right . try access image file using browser address box . 
like localhost/assets/images/image.jpg